Как скопировать/перенести несколько (или все) таблиц из одной базы postgresql в другую?
Как скопировать одну таблицу из одной базы в другую я прочитал здесь.
pg_dump -t table_to_copy source_db | psql target_db

Но не смог найти информацию как скопировать несколько или все таблицы одной командой/запросом. Какие есть клиентские решения (с помощью pg_dump, psql и т.д.) или серверные (SELECT ...)?

.. -t таблица1 -t таблица2 ..

Класс, спасибо! Если оформите как ответ - плюсану. А нет вариантов, чтобы все сразу, ну типа - pg_dump -t * ...?

Если оформите как ответ - плюсану. Плюс за то, что я вместо Вас прочитал справку по опциям командной строки? смешно... А нет вариантов, чтобы все сразу Как полагаете, что задампится, если имён таблиц вообще не указывать? Hint: ответ "ничего" - неправильный.

-t, --table=ШАБЛОН           выгрузить только указанную таблицу(ы)

@Akina благодарю! Однако, если Вы считаете для себя неуместным оформление этого ответа, Вы не будете против если я его оформлю сам со ссылкой на Вас и на nörbörnën. Я заметил Вашу язвительность, но считаю, что таким как я, которые, по разным причинам, не знают где искать и не читают "справки по опциям командной строки" этот ответ поможет.

Вы не будете против если я его оформлю сам со ссылкой на Вас и на nörbörnën. Ни в коем случае. Более того, я считаю, что в подобных случаях самоответ - штука весьма полезная для самого вопрошающего, если он приложит усилия для подробного разбора проблемы и её решения, конечно. по разным причинам, не знают где искать В официальной документации, конечно: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/app-pgdump.html Ну а тут даже и на русском: https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/16/app-pgdump

@nörbörnën спасибо! Если необходимо - Вы можете оформить это как ответ - я его плюсану. Я сам тоже оформлю ответ с Вашим ответом и ответом Akina, если Вы не против.

Особая благодарность выражается Akina и nörbörnën, которые оставили свои ответы в комментариях.
Для копирования нескольких таблиц с перечислением имен:
pg_dump -t table_1 -t table_2 source_db | psql target_db

Для копирования нескольких таблиц по шаблону:
pg_dump -t, --table=ШАБЛОН source_db | psql target_db

Для копирования всех таблиц:
pg_dump source_db | psql target_db

Ссылка на официальную документацию pg_dump на английском и на русском.
